#  Keyboard shortcut to hide/unhide the panel?

Tags: 10.10, keyboard, gnome-panel

Is there a way to assign a keyboard shortcut to hide or unhide a specific gnome-panel?

EDIT: Is there was a way to make a button combination have the auto-hide panel slide out, as if I had hovered my mouse on that side of the screen?

Comment: Great question! I want to know this too! Nothing i could find in either compiz or keyboard shortcuts

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a trick to do that.

**Part One - How to hide/show all gnome panels**

1) Make this file:

```
gedit ~/.gpnaelhs
```

2) Paste this into it:

```
#!/bin/bash

count=0
while read line
do
   keys[$((++count))]="${line}/auto_hide"
done <<EOF
$( gconftool-2 --all-dirs "/apps/panel/toplevels" )
EOF

case $( gconftool-2 --get "${keys[1]}" ) in
   "0" | "false" | "False" )
      new="true"
      ;;
   * )
      new="false"
      ;;
esac

for key in "${keys[@]}"
do
   gconftool-2 --set "$key" --type bool "$new"
done

#End of File
```

3) Save.

4) Make it executable:

```
sudo chmod +x ~/.gpnaelhs
```

5) Make a shortcut for it:

```
gnome-keybinding-properties
```

6) Click "Add" and put a name (p. ex. "Gnome Panel Hide - Unhide")  and the command

```
bash -c '~/.gpnaelhs'
```

[image]

7) Click "Ok"

8) Click "Disable"  and choose your shortcut (p. ex. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + P

[image]

**Part Two - How to hide/show only one gnome panel**

1) First please backup your settings

```
gconftool --dump /apps/panel > ~/.panel.settings.backup.xml
```

and

```
mkdir ~/.panel.folders.backup && cp -r ~/.gconf/apps/panel/toplevels/ ~/.panel.folders.backup/
```

2) Now we have to do 2 things. First: edit the file ~/.gpnaelhs and change "/apps/panel/toplevels" for "/apps/panel/toplevels/panel_0" (change the number as needed).

3) Then: delete the folders named panel_0 or panel_1 or panel_2 ... at /apps/panel/toplevels.

Enjoy!

[Reference](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1345815).

Comment: Thanks a lot! It works, except for one thing; when banishing the panel that is on auto-hide, applications will fill up the entire space of the screen, even if there is a panel on top that isn't set to auto-hide.

I was wondering if there was a way to make a button combination have the auto-hide panel slide out, as if I had hovered my mouse on that side of the screen.

Comment: Now that he's edited his question you can just integrate that comment into your answer.

Comment: Edited the answer to add what you want. I've deleted my comments to make the page more clean ;-)